# My livestock is missing: where to find them?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Recently I kept receiving announcements such as `The Stray Donkey (Tame) has been missing for a week`. At first I thought maybe they just strayed off, but I've lost six animals so far, and I think I'd better take some effort to figure out what's going on to prevent further loss.

[image]

The pasture is placed at the edge of the map. Usually my dwarves don't go to that area, which somehow contributed to the lack of witnesses. Currently I only have one ten-dwarf squad, should I station them near the pasture to monitor it?

[image]

Where have my animals gone? How can I find them back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have gone to live on a farm with all their friends.

Without euphemisms, a missing animal is already dead. An animal or dwarf is missing if it has died, and no dwarf has seen the body.

There are various ways they could have died. I noticed that your missing animals are grazers (herbivores). A grazing animal will starve if left in a cage, or if there is no grass left in its pasture. With the pasture at the edge of the map, a random enemy (goblin, werebeast, predatory animal) may have killed your livestock after coming onto the map. Although less likely in your case, the victim may have dodged of a cliff or into a river.

Relevant quote from the [wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Announcement#Minor_announcements):

> The announcement of the missing (after one week) or dead (after a dwarf sees their corpse) status of a dwarf or tame creature.

And more explicit quote in relevant thread on the official [forum](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=108041.0)

> If your animals are killed and no dwarf sees the bodies, then they are declared missing the same as a dwarf.